# Flexbox putting items next to each other and not centering

Tags: html, css

I'm using a flexbox and it is putting items next to each other and not centering vertically. I got the code to center from http://howtocenterincss.com. Below is my code and what I see. A solution would be appreciated.

```
<div style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;">
    <h1>heading</h1>

    <p>content</p>
  </div>
```

## heading

content

[image: Screenshot of what I see]

Comment: please share your code.

Comment: @Pranaykumar I added it

Answer (score 2):

you need to add `flex-direction` property

```
element {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add flex-direction in your container. One more important concept, you can't align your items vertically center unless you set some height to your container so also add some height in your container div as per your requirement. Also, make sure to use all browser prefixes for cross-browser compatibilities. You can add this code as an internal style or as an external stylesheet.

```
<style>

div{
min-height:100vh;
  display:-webkit-box;
    display:-webkit-flex;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    display:flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap:wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap:wrap;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
-webkit-box-pack:center;
    -webkit-justify-content:center;
    -ms-flex-pack:center;
    justify-content:center;
    -webkit-box-align:center;
    -webkit-align-items:center;
    -ms-flex-align:center;
    align-items:center;
-webkit-box-orient:vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction:normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction:column;
    -ms-flex-direction:column;
    flex-direction:column;
}
</style>
```

These codes will center all the child elements, horizontally and vertically.

Comment: Where do I add that into my file?

Comment: add whole code in your head tag or save code(without style tag) as .css file and add it in your HTML file with the help of link tag.

Comment: I added it with the style tag, but it does not seem to center vertically...

Comment: [Here is my file on GitHub](https://github.com/branchinstitute/branchinstitute.github.io/blob/master/index.html)

Comment: https://codepen.io/pranaysharma995/pen/abvJdoJ codepen link.